# The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it. Even after using dispatcher

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, dispatcher

In WPF I have this code:

```
wrapPanel.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    wrapPanel.Children.Add(myCanvas);
}));
```

When i run this i get

> "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it"

As i know calling `dispatcher.Invoke()` should solve this problem.

Why am i getting this error?
What are the possible reasons for this ?

Since my actual code is too long i didn't paste it all here. By the way I'm a noob.

Comment: Who owns `myCanvas` ?

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: @SB Calling thread owns it. `myCanvas` object is created just before this.

Comment: @SLacks  --  `A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll
The thread '<Thread Ended>' (0x1c08) has exited with code 0 (0x0).` You mean this right?

Comment: Who owns `wrapPanel` ?

Comment: @Sniffer I created `wrapPanel` in WPF XAML editor. Im kind of new to WPF.

Comment: Post the full code and XAML.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the code to create myCanvas and add it to the wrap panel inside a 'Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(Action<T> action)' call?  I'm not an expert on Dispatcher/threading but that pattern seems to resolve these issues by always referencing the WPF/UI dispatcher in cases where I haven't created my own dispatchers.

Comment: @HighCore Full code is unnecessarily long but i can explain what i try to do. I have `wrapPanel` in XAML, and i have Image[] array in C#. When an event occurs i add Image[k] one by one to a new `myCanvas` instance then to `wrapPanel` using `wrapPanel.Children.Add(myCanvas);`. i call this function using a new thread for this process to be smooth. again im a noob.

Comment: @KamalRathnayake the preferred way to do that in WPF is by using an `ItemsControl`. Manipulating UI elements in procedural code in WPF is not needed nor desired.

Answer (score 1):

When using WPF, we work with data objects that are displayed by relating UI objects. Using `Binding`s, we update the UI by manipulating the *data* objects. I would implement something like this for your situation... first create a `DependencyProperty` in your `MainWindow.cs` to bind to:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Items", typeof(ObservableCollection<Image>), typeof(MainWindow), 
    new UIPropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<Image>()));

public ObservableCollection<Image> Items
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<Image>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
}
```

Then add the UI code that will display the data property:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Finally, we *must* set the `DataContext` (this is the *least* preferable way to do it, but the simplest for this example):

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

There is no need for any `Dispatcher.Invoke` calls to achieve this.